# I've tried everything and it still says that PIP is an invalid command in the command prompt

Tags: python, pip

I've looked at so many Stack Overflow questions and I've tried everything:
I installed get-pip.py, I ran "python get-pip.py" in the correct folder in the Command Prompt but it still says that pip is an invalid command.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: One thing that worked for me when pip didn't work is to prefix my commands with "python -m"

e.g. "python -m pip install flask"

Comment: Have you added Python to your PATH variables?

Comment: Have you tried installing with conda?

Comment: Some information on your operating system and the way you installed python and tried to install pip would be useful to assess what could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try `python -m pip install <module here>` or `py -m pip install <module here>`. It worked for me without adding pip to PATH, although I recommend doing so. Also, make sure that you don't have multiple versions of python on your system. That can mess things up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows, the simplest solution is just to uninstall python and to reinstall it. Then when running the python setup program, make sure to tick the "add python to PATH" option

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that "pip" is also added to your PATH in "Environment Variables" just like you add PATH of your python. So once go to your "Environment Variables" and check if this folder is included `C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts` since this folder contains your "pip"